# Vitest React Redux - expected "spy" to be called with arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, vitest

i getting error like this when I want to test my React application which uses Redux, I want to test the thunk function register
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ [Function] ]

```
// action.js
function asyncRegisterUser({ name, email, password }) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(showLoading());
        try {
            await api.register({ name, email, password });
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
        dispatch(hideLoading());
    };
}

export {
    asyncRegisterUser,
};

// action.test.js

import { hideLoading, showLoading } from 'react-redux-loading-bar';
import {
 afterEach, beforeEach, describe, expect, it, vi,
} from 'vitest';
import api from '../../utils/api';
import { asyncRegisterUser } from './action';

const fakeRegisterResponse = {
    id: 'john_doe',
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    avatar: 'https://generated-image-url.jpg',
};

const fakeRegisterInput = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    password: 'JohnDoe',
};

const fakeErrorResponse = new Error('Ups, something went wrong');

describe('asyncRegisterUser thunk', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        api._registerUser = api.register;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        api.register = api._registerUser;

        delete api._registerUser;
    });

    it('should dispatch action correctly when register success', async () => {
        api.register = () => Promise.resolve(fakeRegisterResponse);
        const dispatch = vi.fn();

        await asyncRegisterUser(fakeRegisterInput)(dispatch);

        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(showLoading());
        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            asyncRegisterUser(fakeRegisterInput), //ERROR HERE
        );
        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(hideLoading());
    });

    it('should dispatch action and call alert correctly when register failed', async () => {
        api.register = () => Promise.reject(fakeErrorResponse);

        const dispatch = vi.fn();

        window.alert = vi.fn();

        await asyncRegisterUser(fakeRegisterInput)(dispatch);

        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(showLoading());
        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(hideLoading());
        expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeErrorResponse.message);
    });
});
```

i wanna make test using vitest on react redux thunk function when i call register function, should dispatch action correctly when register success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your `asyncRegisterUser` action creator the `dispatch` function is only called twice, once with `showLoading()` and a second time with `hideLoading()`.

```js
function asyncRegisterUser({ name, email, password }) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(showLoading()); // <-- dispatch call #1
    try {
      await api.register({ name, email, password });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
    dispatch(hideLoading()); // <-- dispatch call #2
  };
}
```

It would probably be very bad for your `asyncRegisterUser` action to trigger calling itself so probably want to assert that this ***does not*** happen.

```js
it('should dispatch action correctly when register success', async () => {
  api.register = () => Promise.resolve(fakeRegisterResponse);
  const dispatch = vi.fn();

  await asyncRegisterUser(fakeRegisterInput)(dispatch);

  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(showLoading()); // <-- dispatch #1

  // assert asyncRegisterUser action isn't recursively called
  expect(dispatch).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    asyncRegisterUser(fakeRegisterInput),
  );

  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(hideLoading()); // <-- dispatch #2
});
```

Otherwise, remove the middle assertion since `dispatch` ***obviously*** doesn't call `asyncRegisterUser`.

```js
it('should dispatch action correctly when register success', async () => {
  api.register = () => Promise.resolve(fakeRegisterResponse);
  const dispatch = vi.fn();

  await asyncRegisterUser(fakeRegisterInput)(dispatch);

  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(showLoading()); // <-- dispatch #1
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(hideLoading()); // <-- dispatch #2
});
```